# How to get first row value from third table while joining three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm new to mssql .Here am trying to get values from database by joining three tables .

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2 :

[image]

**Here the image there is a possibility for a single user can have multiple image id** form this I need to take any one of the image.

Table 3 :

[image]

Here am joining the Table 1 and Table 2 by using **H_ID** 
and Table 2 and Table 3 by using **IMG_ID.**

What I want to do is Need to get all the colum values from Table 1 and Table 2 But the first URL from the Table 3.

In this case an employee has multiple images in the Table I need to take the  1 URL.

Result should be like this :

[image]

Query :

```
SELECT T1.H_ID AS 'ID',
       T1.NAME,
       T1.ROLE,
       T2.SALARY,
       T3.IMAGE 
FROM TABLE1 T1 

JOIN TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.H_ID T2.H_ID  

JOIN TABLE3 T3 
ON T3.IMG_ID = T2.IMG_ID 

WHERE T1.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

**Now this query returns 3 rows for the id H_ID = 1001 but It should be a single row.**

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()`

```
with cte as

(SELECT T1.H_ID AS 'ID',T1.NAME,T1.ROLE,T2.SALARY,T3.IMAGE 
,row_number() over(partition by T2.img_id order by T3.id) rn
FROM TABLE1 T1 

JOIN TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.H_ID T2.H_ID  

JOIN TABLE3 T3 
ON T3.IMG_ID = T2.IMG_ID WHERE T1.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'

) select * from cte where rn=1
```

After you comments it seems you need subquery

```
select T1.*,T2.sal,a.url
    FROM TABLE1 T1     
    JOIN TABLE2 T2 
    ON T1.H_ID T2.H_ID
    left join ( select min(id),img_id,url from table3 group by img_id,url) a
    on T2.IMG_ID= a.img_id
  WHERE T1.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: How to should I change if there is a possibility of having multiple image ID for a single user in Table 2 @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: @Zhu what you need regarding that

Comment: I need to take all the users with only one image URL from Table 3 along with other table values ,Please find the edited tables@Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: @Zhu which one url you need from table 3

Comment: Image could be anything belongs to that user not specif @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190293/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-zhu).

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can simply use `OUTER APPLY` and `TOP 1` for that

```
SELECT T1.H_ID AS 'ID',
       T1.NAME,
       T1.ROLE,
       T2.SALARY,
       T3.IMAGE 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.H_ID T2.H_ID  
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 T3.IMAGE 
            FROM TABLE3 T3 WHERE T3.IMG_ID = T2.IMG_ID 
            --ORDER BY <column_name> --to take top 1 value in specific order
            ) T3        
WHERE T1.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```